# SQL: Selecting data from another table using foreign keys

Tags: sql

I'm newbie in SQL and for purpose of learning I'm trying to make some queries in SQL. So i made these two tables:

```
account(id, email, password)
address(id, city, street, c_id(foreign key for account))
```

Now I would like to select all emails given a city. Bellow what i tried.

```
SELECT email
FROM account
WHERE id=(SELECT c_id
          FROM address
          WHERE city='new york');
```

This query is not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
SELECT email
FROM account
WHERE id in (SELECT c_id
             FROM address
             WHERE city='new york');
```

or

```
SELECT email
FROM account 
    JOIN address ON account.id = address.c_id
WHERE address.city='new york'
```